# TS not accepting x | y value as element of (x | y)[] list

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript HardHat project

```
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: process.env.INFURA_GOERLI_ENDPOINT,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY],
    }
  }
};
```

when I hover over `accounts:`, VSCode informs me that the type is `(property) accounts: (string | undefined)[]`.

However, I am getting an error on the value `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY`, which of of type `string | undefined`

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

If `accounts` is a list of elements typed `string|undefined`, why is TS insisting on elements being `strings`? `undefined` elements also belong to the set of `string|undefined` elements.

I can fix it by adding a type assertion

```
accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY as string]
```

but this seems unnecessary. A value of type `string | undefined` should be a valid element of a list of type `(string | undefined)[]`. What's going wrong?

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  Right now I don't have the definitions or declarations so it's hard to say why the compiler would be complaining.  Presumably the definition of `HardhatUserConfig` is important?  What is it?

Comment: @jcalz if when I hover over `accounts:` VSCode informs me that it's of type `(string | undefined)[]` and that `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY` is of type `string | undefined`, isn't that all the information we need as far as type declarations go?

Comment: This is a wild guess: you are misinterpreting the info VSCode is giving you; it's telling you the type of the `accounts` property of your initializer object, which is *not* the type of the corresponding property in the `HardhatUserConfig` type.  If you changed `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY` to `new Date()` then you'd probably see `Date[]` as the property type, but that doesn't mean that `HardhatUserConfig` wants that.

Comment: "isn't that all the information we need as far as type declarations go?" No, that's why I asked for the type definitions.  A [mre] is almost always helpful.  Possibly if you go through the exercise of providing one the problem will become obvious to you, and if not, then everyone else is in a better position to help you.

Comment: @jcals You are right. I changed `[process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]` to `[7]` and VSCode now shows `(property) accounts: number[]`. I assumed VSCode was showing the type definition. If you post this as an answer I plan to accept it.

Comment: For this to be useful to future readers I think the question should be [edit]ed to include all the necessary information.  So the definition of `HardhatUserConfig` (or a toy version of it) plus the full error message (earlier lines are probably relevant), and then the answer would be that your IDE is telling you the type of the property you're hovering over and not the type the property would have to be in order to prevent an error.  As written now, the question is largely misdirecting attention toward the compatibility of `undefined` with `string | undefined` and away from the core issue.

Comment: @jcalz if I modified the question to include that information, the source of confusion might disappear and the question could read as contradictory/self-answering. Future readers might be puzzled as to how I could even have such a confusion if I knew the real type definition of `HardhatUserConfig`. How do you suggest I edit the question without obscuring the original motivation and source of confusion?

Comment: If the full background information necessary to answer the question authoritatively (as opposed to just guessing) would make the answer so obvious that the question itself seems unmotivated, then... delete the question?  Alternatively you can leave the question largely as-is and post an answer yourself with all the necessary information missing from the question that shows how the premise of the original question was sort of a red herring, and maybe future readers will benefit from that.  In either case I'm going to disengage here.  Good luck!